# SQL Backup Automation with powershell

Tags: mysql, powershell

I want to try and automate a SQL backup with a powershell script. I am basing my script around this command

```
Backup-SqlDatabase -ServerInstance Workstation\SQLEXPRESS -BackupFile C:\Backup\SQLBak -Database ExampleDB -Credential (Get-Credential sa)
```

But I want to be able to add my credentials automatically. Is there a way to include a variable that provides that information?

Comment: You can save your credentials as such: `(Get-Credential) | Export-CliXml -Path $path` and then re-use them in your script: `$credential = Import-CliXml -Path $path`

Comment: Note if you're doing this as a scheduled task that runs as SYSTEM, you need to run the above command as system since it's using DPAPI to encrypt your credentials.  You can accomplish this by using psexec or a scheduled task.